# SQL retorna dois registros para um campo, como junta-los?

Tags: sql, db2

Tenho o seguinte código SQL no DB2:

```
SELECT p.nome_pessoa, a.dt_nascimento, alc.matricula, d.numero_documento, d.id_tdoc_pessoa FROM pessoas as p
INNER JOIN alunos as a ON p.id_pessoa = a.id_pessoa
INNER JOIN acad_alunos_cursos as alc ON alc.id_aluno = a.id_aluno
INNER JOIN doc_pessoas as d ON p.id_pessoa = d.id_pessoa WHERE p.nome_pessoa = 'Vitor Lucas Pires Cordovil'
```

Após a execução da query eu tenho o seguinte retorno:

> NOME - DATA DE NASCIMENTO - MATRÍCULA - NUMERO DOCUMENTO - TIPO DOCUMENTO
>
> Vitor Lucas Pires Cordovil -  1994-02-27 -    2014300028 - 951.249.865-X3 -                               1
>
> Vitor Lucas Pires Cordovil -  1994-02-27 -    2012430028 -            10491872 -      3

Ele me retorna os dois registros, porque existem dois documentos cadastrado para a pessoa, quando o tipo de documento é 1 então é um RG, quando é 3 é um CPF. Só que eu quero que a query me retorne apenas um registro com duas colunas: RG e CPF, tudo na mesma linha. Como fazer?

Comment: Algo assim: NOME - DATA DE NASCIMENTO - MATRÍCULA - NUMERO DOCUMENTO (TIPO) - NUMERO DOCUMENTO (TIPO)?

Comment: Não, algo assim: NOME - DATA DE NASCIMENTO - MATRÍCULA - RG - CPF

Comment: Mas são somente RG e CPF que são cadastrados?

Comment: Não, tem vários outros, mas os únicos que preciso são esses dois.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu faria algo assim:

```
SELECT p.nome_pessoa, a.dt_nascimento, alc.matricula, df.numero_documento as RG, dj.numero_documento as CPF, df.id_tdoc_pessoa as df, dj.id_tdoc_pessoa as dj FROM pessoas as p
INNER JOIN alunos as a ON p.id_pessoa = a.id_pessoa
INNER JOIN acad_alunos_cursos as alc ON alc.id_aluno = a.id_aluno
LEFT JOIN doc_pessoas as df ON p.id_pessoa = df.id_pessoa and df.id_tdoc_pessoa = 1
LEFT JOIN doc_pessoas as dj ON p.id_pessoa = dj.id_pessoa and dj.id_tdoc_pessoa = 3
WHERE p.nome_pessoa = 'Vitor Lucas Pires Cordovil'
```

Que seria dar um novo JOIN na tabela doc_pessoas, restringindo pra cada tipo específico, no seu caso 1 e 3. Usei LEFT em vez de INNER pra que a linha seja exibida mesmo em caso de não haver o valor pra tipo = 1 ou 3.

Comment: Qual seria o resultado do seu codigo, @iuri?

Comment: O resultado seria os dois registros numa linha apenas, conforme ele imaginou.

Comment: @iuristona, quase funcionou, ele trouxe o CPF nos campos do RG e do CPF.

Comment: Consegui já! Só modifiquei no select no primeiro df.numero_documento eu pus dj.numero_documento.

Comment: Iuri, sua resposta ajudou, mas poderia dar uma explicação sobre o que você fez? Pra não só eu, mas como outras pessoas também entenderem. Valeu.

Comment: Desculpe, trouxe os mesmos valores porque eu copiei e colei, deixando o prefixo em ambos casos como df, já corrigi na resposta. Tentei dar uma breve explicação sobre qual foi a ideia, espero que tenha ajudado a entender melhor.

Comment: Entendi sim. Muito obrigado.